# What can I do to avoid the app crashing when it encounters a null value?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsnull

What can I do to avoid the app crashing when it encounters a null value?

the error message I get is:

```
-[NSNull isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.
```

I tried this conditional statement to check for a null value, but it still crashes. listingWebAddress is a `NSString`.

```
 if (listingWebAddress == nil)
    {
        [webLabel setText:@""];

    } else {

    [webLabel setText:listingWebAddress];

    }
```

it works fine when a "listingWebAddress" exists.

thanks for the help :)

Update:

thanks to The Tiger's response the code now works. The solution was:

```
 if (![listingWebAddress isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
    {
        // do your task here

        [webLabel setText:listingWebAddress];

    } else {

        [webLabel setText:@"no web url"];

    }
```

Comment: @Kerni How about answering the question instead of spamming?! NSNull is quite a common issue, especially when it comes to JSONs returned from APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** If it is `NSString` you can check its **length** and if it is an `NSArray` you check its **count**.

**2.** You can simply put it in if condition, condition will return `YES` only in case of the object is not **nil**. 
**Example:**

```
if (object)
{
    //do your task here
}
```

**3.** In **Objective-C** You can check it by its class.

```
if (![object isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
{
   // do your task here
}
```

**The NSNull class defines a singleton object used to represent null values in collection objects (which don’t allow nil values).**

Comment: thanks! it is an NSString. I updated my code above and got rid of the mutableCopy. I then tried    if (listingWebAddress)
    {
        [webLabel setText:listingWebAddress];

    } but it still crashes with -[NSNull isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Of course you are calling `isEqualToString:` method by an `NSNull` object while it is use for an `NSString` object. Have you checked its class by `[listingWebAddress :isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]` ?

Comment: that worked! thanks so much! it was getting annoying :D  if (![listingWebAddress isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
    {
        // do your task here
        
        [webLabel setText:listingWebAddress];

    } else {
    
        [webLabel setText:@"no web url"];

    }

Answer (score 0):

It looks like listingWebAddress is already NSNull, which doesn't support method mutableCopy. I would change condition to:

```
if ( [listingWebAddress isKindOfClass: [NSNull class]] == NO){
  ... rest of logic 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(listingWebAddress !=[NSNull null]
{
   //your code
}
```